# clean summation involving index of numpy arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I've occasionally but not frequently used numpy.  I'm now needing to do some summations where the sums involve the row/column indices.

I have an `m x n` array S.  I want to do the create a new `m x n` array whose 's,i' entry is

```
-c i S[s,i] + g (i+1)S[s,i+1] + (s+1)S[s+1,i-1]
```

So say `S=np.array([[1,2],[3,4], [5,6]])` the result I want is

```
-c*np.array([[0*1, 1*2],[0*3, 1*4],[0*5, 1*6]]) 
+ g*np.array([[1*2, 2*0],[1*4, 2*0],[1*6, 2*0]]) 
+ np.array([[1*0, 1*3],[2*0, 2*5],[3*0, 3*0]])
```

(that's not all the terms in my equation, but I feel like knowing how to do this would be enough to complete what I'm after).

I think what I will need to do is create a new array whose rows are just the index of the rows and another corresponding for columns.  Then do some component-wise multiplication.  But this is well outside what I normally do in my research, so I've taken a few wrong steps already.

*note*: It is understood that where the indices refer to something outside my array the value is zero.

---

Is there a clean way to do the summation I've described above?

Comment: Could you make a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do it in several steps, due to your possible out-of-bounds indexing:

```
import numpy as np
S = np.array([[1,2],[3,4], [5,6]])
c = np.random.rand()
g = np.random.rand()

m,n = S.shape

Stmp1 = S*np.arange(0,n)         # i*S[s,i]
Stmp2 = S*np.arange(0,m)[:,None] # s*S[s,i]

# the answer:
Sout = -c*Stmp1
Sout[:,:-1] = Sout[:,:-1] + g*Stmp1[:,1:]
Sout[:-1,1:] = Sout[:-1,1:] + Stmp2[1:,:-1]

# only for control:
Sout2 = -c*np.array([[0*1, 1*2],[0*3, 1*4],[0*5, 1*6]]) \
       + g*np.array([[1*2, 2*0],[1*4, 2*0],[1*6, 2*0]]) \
       +   np.array([[1*0, 1*3],[2*0, 2*5],[3*0, 3*0]])
```

Check:

```
In [431]: np.all(Sout==Sout2)
Out[431]: True
```

I introduced auxiliary arrays for `i*S[s,i]` and `s*S[s,i]`. While this is clearly not necessary, it makes the code easier to read. We could've easily sliced into the `np.arange(0,n)` calls directly, but unless memory is not an issue, I find this approach much more straightforward.